# grand total empty in table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've the following pbix https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amd7BXzYs7AVlXPjuP0CfblYyc5K?e=kNnEiN

I've the following measure

```
Measure2 = var _1=max(MaxPropre[Nb]) +0
var _min = minx(ALLSELECTED('Date Filter'), 'date Filter'[Date]) var ax = maxx(ALLSELECTED('MaxPropre'), 'MaxPropre'[Date])
var _max = maxx(ALLSELECTED('date Filter'), 'date Filter'[Date]) VAR dt =SELECTEDVALUE ( 'DimDate'[date] )
return
CALCULATE(if((max('DimDate'[Date]) <_min || max('DimDate'[Date]) >_max ) , BLANK(), if(ax >=dt,[const],0)))
```

why I'm not getting the grand total please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another measure like:

```
Measure3 = IF(HASONEFILTER('DimDate'[date]),[Measure2],SUMX(VALUES('DimDate'[date]),[Measure2]))
```

...and use it in your table.

[This site explains what you're dealing with fairly well.](https://archerpoint.com/how-to-make-measures-total-correctly-in-power-bi-tables/#:%7E:text=To%20correct%20the%20totals%20not,around%20the%20default%20totaling%20calculation.)